# PHP: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, member

The error occurs on line 42:

```
$result->bind_param("ssssisssss", $Firma, $Partner, $Abteilung, $Strasse, $PLZ, $Ort, $Telefon, $Email, $Website, $Info );
```

This is the whole prepared statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `firmen` (`Firma`, `Ansprechpartner`, `Abteilung`, `Strasse`, `PLZ`, `Ort`, `Telefon`, `Email`, `Website`, `Zusatzinfos`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";     
$result = $db->prepare( $sql ); 
$result->bind_param("ssssisssss", $Firma, $Partner, $Abteilung, $Strasse, $PLZ, $Ort, $Telefon, $Email, $Website, $Info );
$result->execute();
```

I can't find the mistake, I already read almost every question with the same mistake an I also compared my Code with a lot of Tutorial and it looks exactly the same...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in front of `$db->prepare()` and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

...usually this occurs when you have an error in prepare statement, 
It might happen that you have a typo in sql prepare. to verify that. 
check the error with this

```
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".TB_ADMINISTRATION."(name, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"); 
       if(!$stmt)  //if there is an error, then it will be shown!. 
         { // show error                                                                                                       
          echo $this->db->error;
          } else {
           // everything is good to go !. 
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, lost so much time assuming the error was in "bind_param" and it was just a stupid typo in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

one extra parameters  so i removed first parameter:
change the following

```
$result->bind_param("ssssisssss", $Firma, $Partner, $Abteilung, $Strasse, $PLZ, $Ort, $Telefon, $Email, $Website, $Info );
```

with

```
$result->bind_param($Firma, $Partner, $Abteilung, $Strasse, $PLZ, $Ort, $Telefon, $Email, $Website, $Info );
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error-message says, `$result` seems to be not an object. try to debug this by using `var_dump($result);` right after your prepare-call.

It looks like you're using PHP's PDO. In that case, take a look at the documentation.

If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

ALso, what is "sisssssss"?
10 values are needed and you insert 11.

Hm, change this query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `firmen` (`Firma`, `Ansprechpartner`, `Abteilung`, `Strasse`, `PLZ`, `Ort`, `Telefon`, `Email`, `Website`, `Zusatzinfos`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Into this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO firmen ('Firma', 'Ansprechpartner', 'Abteilung', 'Strasse', 'PLZ', 'Ort', 'Telefon', 'Email', 'Website', 'Zusatzinfos') 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

This one `'` and ` are not the same.

Comment: I already used "var_dump" and it returned "bool(false)", I also changed the number of values from 11 to 10 but it doesn't seem to change anything, still getting the message

Comment: Have you echoed your query already? Seems like it can't prepare the query so it'll return false. So something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have you have 10 value in the insert statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `firmen` (`Firma`, `Ansprechpartner`, `Abteilung`, `Strasse`, `PLZ`, `Ort`, `Telefon`, `Email`, `Website`, `Zusatzinfos`)
```

and you are giving 11 parameters in the `bind->param()` like this

```
$result->bind_param("ssssisssss", $Firma, $Partner, $Abteilung, $Strasse, $PLZ, $Ort, $Telefon, $Email, $Website, $Info );
```

So you have to corret the number of arguments. So either add another column in the insert statement or remove one value from the `bind->param()` and keep your insert statement as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the below code

$sql = "INSERT INTO `firmen` (`Firma`, `Ansprechpartner`, `Abteilung`, `Strasse`, `PLZ`, `Ort`, `Telefon`, `Email`, `Website`, `Zusatzinfos`)

delete the apostrophe ('') from each as

$sql = "INSERT INTO firmen (Firma, Ansprechpartner, Abteilung, Strasse, PLZ, Ort, Telefon, Email, Website, Zusatzinfos)