# MySQL 'fatal error'

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an error in my code, I've been googling it and trying to find out what the problem is. As far as I know it's been a problem executing my sql code (around variable $so). Could anyone help me out?

**Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ... on line 15**

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = "";
    $dbuser = "";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $so = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht");
    $so->execute();

    $result = $so->get_result();

    echo "<form name='overzicht' method='post'>";
    echo "<table align='center' border='2'>
    <tr>
            <th>Ordernr</th>
            <th>Klantnaam</th>
            <th>Productnaam</th>
            <th>ProductID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $ordernr = $row['ordernr'];
    $klantnaam = $row['klantnaam'];
    $productnaam = $row['productnaam'];
    $productid = $row['productid'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='150px'>" . $ordernr . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='150px'>" . $klantnaam . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='300px'>" . $productnaam . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100px'>" . $productid . "</td>";

    echo "<td width='200px'><select name='status[$ordernr]'>
     <option>" . $status . "</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Niet besteld")
      echo "<option>Niet besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Besteld")
      echo "<option>Besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie")
      echo "<option>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar vestiging")
      echo "<option>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Ontvangen")
      echo "<option>Ontvangen</option>";
    echo "</select></td>";

    echo "<td align='center' width='50px'><input name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='$ordernr'></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='wijzigen' value='Wijzigingen Opslaan'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='verwijderen' value='Verwijderen'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

    $statuses = $_POST['status'];
    $delete = $_POST['delete'];
    $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'];

    if (isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {
        foreach($statuses as $ordernr => $status)
        {
            if($status != "")
                $dbupdate = "UPDATE overzicht SET status='$status' WHERE ordernr='$ordernr'";
                $query = mysqli_query($con,$dbupdate);

            header("refresh: 0;");
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['verwijderen'])) {
            foreach($del_id as $value){
            $dbdelete = "DELETE FROM overzicht WHERE ordernr='".$value."'";
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$dbdelete);
        }
        header("refresh: 0;");
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244705/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object

Comment: Are you sure you have a table besteloverzicht?

Comment: Find out the error by adding `var_dump($con->error)` after preparing the statement.

Comment: @Mihai Yes, definitely! I'm not quite sure why it's giving me this error. I've used this "application" in the past, just booted it up again after two months and it threw me this error. Could it be MySQL settings I have to adjust or anything?

Comment: @GergoErdosi when I put that between the prepare and execute line, it's giving me this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$so' (T_VARIABLE) in ... on line 16

Comment: Maybe you`ve been hacked run the sql directly on mysql server.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I didn't have the table besteloverzicht anymore, someone changed the name of it.. should've checked it immediatly when you said it. My bad, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the table `besteloverzicht` doesn't exist?
Please replace

```
$so = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht");
```

with

```
$so = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht") OR die(mysqli_error());
```

That should give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks to your first sentence it made me relook the table name, I was about 100% sure that nothing had been changed, but a colleague of mine changed the name from besteloverzicht to overzicht.. sigh.

Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your prepare statement to produce an error in case it fails

```
if (!($so = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
}
```

This may give you a better insight

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM besteloverzicht');